# Visual Studio 2017: ASP.NET MVC Project cannot open after windows 10 updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio  2017 for my Web Application Development by using ASP.NET MVC Framework. I have no problem along all the way to open my project. However, yesterday I just updated my windows 10. Today I cannot open my previous visual studio project with following

```
An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged in "C:\Users\chan.yoonghon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_3a4e3740\ActivityLog.xml".

Exception details:
System.ArgumentException: The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
Parameter name: instantiation
   at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.Reflection.TypeRef.get_ResolvedType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeComposition.RuntimeImport.get_ImportingSiteType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeComposition.RuntimeImport.get_ImportingSiteTypeWithoutCollection()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeComposition.RuntimeImport.get_IsLazy()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeComposition.RuntimeImport.get_LazyFactory()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.SatisfyImports()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.SatisfyImmediateImports()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass53_0.<CreateExport>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass70_0`2.<GetExports>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[T]()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetService[T]()
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.PivotNavigatorServices.get_AttachedCollectionService()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPane.RefillNavigator()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPane.OnToolWindowCreated()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, UInt32 flags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolWindowFactory.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, UInt32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

I not even able to create a new Visual Studio ASP.NET Project also with following error.

```
The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
Parameter name: instantiation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to either repair or reinstall visual studio.

Go to Start >> Visual Studio Installer >> Run it >> Klick the icon next to Launch >> Repair
[image: Repair Visual Studio]